# Django Channels code is working on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, django-channels

I am writing a chat application using Django and Channels (new websocket implementation for Django). Users first enter a wait room, until at least 3 other people have joined, then they are directed to a chat room. The code works fine for Chrome, but is not working correctly for Firefox. Here is how it works:

1. On a new connect to the channel/websocket the server checks to see if at least three people are in the wait room (in consumers.py).
2. If at least three people are present it broadcasts a message to the channel/websocket using the Group function telling them to redirect.
3. The message is received by the clients and it executes a redirection in javascript.

Here are the steps I’ve taken to debug the problem:

1. The code works in browsers other than Firefox (e.g. Chrome).
2. The code works if the first two clients arriving to the wait room are Firefox and the last one (that triggers the server) is Chrome. It redirects all three clients.
3. If the first two clients are Chrome and the last client (that triggers the server) is Firefox it redirects the Chrome clients but not the Firefox client.
4. The problem is unlikely to be with the javascript running the redirection because replacing the code with a simple alert message (upon the client receiving the Group statement) is also not working in Firefox (but does work in Chrome). It is as if the Firefox client never receives the Group message when it is the client that triggers the server.
5. The chat uses channels and works on all browsers including Firefox. It successfully connects, sends messages, receives messages, and disconnects.

Based on these debugging steps I think something is going wrong when Firefox instigates the server code that executes the Group redirect. Do you have any suggestions for what might be going wrong? Do you have any suggestions that would help identify the problem?

Here is the code in consumers.py that I think is causing the problem:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
@channel_session
def wait_connect(message):
    try:
        wait_room, created = WaitRoom.objects.get_or_create(title=title)

    except WaitRoom.DoesNotExist:
        log.debug('ws room does not exist title=%s', title)
        return

    Group('wait-'+title, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).add(message.reply_channel)
    wait_user,created = wait_room.users.get_or_create(user=message.user)

    userlist = WaitUser.objects.filter(wait_room=wait_room,is_active=1)

    if len(userlist)>=3:    
        t = {t['url']='redirecturl'}        
        Group('wait-'+title, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).send({'text': json.dumps(t)})
```

Here is the javascript code that is executing the redirect:

```
$(function() {

var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
var chatsock = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host  + window.location.pathname);



chatsock.onmessage = function(message) {
    var data = JSON.parse(message.data);      

    window.location.replace(data.url);        

};});
```

Comment: ah... interesting... come again why not it's not working..

Comment: I am not sure why it is working. The problem is that in Firefox the client isn't always being redirected. I believe it is not working because of a problem with the Group statement in consumers.py when the client uses Firefox.